# Oracle SQL how to find count less than avg

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

my code is like :

```
SELECT    
    number,
    name,
    count(*) as "the number of correct answer"
FROM
    table1 NATURAL JOIN table2
WHERE
    answer = 'T'
GROUP BY
    number,
    name
HAVING
    count(*) < avg(count(*))
ORDER BY
    count(*);
```

Here I want to find the group with count less than the average number of count for each group, but here I failed to use HAVING or WHERE, could anyone help me?
How can I only select the `1   name1   2` since avg of count is (2+6+7)/3 = 5 and only 2 is less than avg.

```
number name count
1      name1 2
2      name2 6
3      name3 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to *never* use natural joins.  They obfuscate the query and make the query a maintenance nightmore.

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT number, name,
             COUNT(*) as num_correct,
             AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () as avg_num_correct
      FROM table1 JOIN
           table2
           USING (?). -- be explicit about the column name
      WHERE answer = 'T'
      GROUP BY number, name
     ) t
WHERE num_correct < avg_num_correct;
```

As with your version of the query, this filters out all groups that have no correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would place your current query logic into a CTE, and then tag on the average count in the process:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT number, name, COUNT(*) AS cnt,
           AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS avg_cnt
    FROM table1
    NATURAL JOIN table2
    WHERE answer = 'T'
    GROUP BY number, name
)

SELECT number, name, cnt AS count
FROM cte
WHERE cnt < avg_cnt;
```

Here we are using the `AVG()` function as an *analytic* function, with the window being the entire aggregated table.  This means it will find the average of the counts per group, across all groups (*after* aggregation).  Window functions (almost) always evaluate last.